# Regular expression for only fixed 8 digit numeric value, no spaces allowed ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i want an regular expression which allows employee id to accept but employee id is only 8 digit numeric expression no less or no more , without any spaces and characters or any other special characters ?

Comment: How about `[0-9]{8}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this simple regex:

```
^\d{8}$
```